# How to get Twilio SMS StatusCallback from Gravity form?

Tags: wordpress, sms, twilio, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I have installed GravityForm on my Wordpress, and the GravityForm Twilio addon. So I can easily send SMS from a web form and store the entries in my WordPress database.

My problem is that I have no SMS StatusCallback and I need it as a confirmation and attach it to the form entry.

It seems that it's possible (https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages#monitor-the-status-of-your-message) but I have no idea if this is big work or just minutes.

Comment: @philnash is correct, is there a configuration file somewhere, where you can define the SMS callback URLs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It's possible to [monitor the status of an SMS message with Twilio using a status callback URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages#monitor-the-status-of-your-message), however the status callback URL needs to be set by the code that sends the message.

To add this to the Gravity Forms add on you would need to edit the code of the plugin as well as provide a URL for Twilio to make the callback to.

I've not worked with Gravity Forms before and I don't know whether it's possble to edit the add-ons. You might want to check with [Gravity Forms support](https://www.gravityforms.com/support/) to see if it is possible or to raise a feature request to add status callbacks to the Twilio add-on.

Comment: thanks,do you know if it is easier if i use Twilio core and ACF form (acf/save_post) ?

Comment: I don't know what would be easier I'm afraid. I've not worked with WP plugins for a long time and I'm not familiar with either.

Comment: instead of monitoring, is it possible that the receiver of the SMS send manually an answer "ok message received" ?

Comment: It all depends on what you want to do in your application. All of this can be built, I'm just not an expert in how to make this happen within WordPress plugins. If you control how you send messages, you can set a `statusCallback` URL and receive those status updates in your application. If you want to receive incoming messages to your application you will need to set up to receive incoming webhooks from Twilio too. It's all up to you on how you want to achieve this.